# SQL Optional Parameters - Performance Difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Is there a significant performance difference using ISNULL vs. NULL OR in the where clause for "optional" parameters? For instance:

Example 1:

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE (@EmployeeID IS NULL OR EmployeeID = @EmployeeID);
```

vs.

Example 2:

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE EmployeeID = ISNULL(@EmployeeID, EmployeeID);
```

I think the second approach is more readable, but curious if there is a performance penalty using the second approach vs. first.

Comment: The query plan is the same in SQL Server, I remember Oracle treating that differently.

Comment: As written both will prevent an index seek in the case where `@EmployeeID` is not null. This can be avoided with both of them if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Comment: The performance problems with this kind of queries is not the different ways you choose to implement the conditions, it's the cashing of the query plan that will be best for a single set of parameters supplied but might be terrible for another set of parameters. This is a well known problem with catch all queries. So well known that there are a lot of blog posts about it.

Comment: Here is one such excellent blog post on this topic. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 0):

Example 3:

```
IF @EmployeeID IS NULL
    SELECT * FROM tblEmployees 
ELSE 
    SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID;
```

Comment: I should've been more specific. I'm referring to SELECTs where there may be more than one optional param...used for instance on a search screen.  SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE (@EmployeeID IS NULL OR EmployeeID = @EmployeeID) AND (@EmployeeFirstName IS NULL OR EmployeeFirstName = @EmployeeFirstName). Obviously I wouldn't want a bunch of IF ELSEs with different queries for this type of situation.

Answer (score -1):

There is no clear cut winner.

Both prevent Index Seek.

Both promote Parameter Sniffing.

So if plam is not Trivial or not GOOD Enough i.e it is Cost Base optimization
then only you can say which one is better.

i)    `SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE (@EmployeeID IS NULL OR EmployeeID = @EmployeeID);`

```
or
```

ii)    `SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE EmployeeID = ISNULL(@EmployeeID, EmployeeID);`

One thing for sure that,  `Estimated Number of Rows` in `i)` is 3 times higher than `ii)` and in both case EStimated numer of rows is wrong or quite different

If Search query is very important and it is Hit more and it contain millions of rows then use dynamic sql and use `sp_executesql` .

Comment: Instead of dynamic SQL just call one of two separate procedures.